# Android 6 is not able to read directory/files from Sdcard

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdcard

Before Android-6 everything was working fine in my Application. There are some file in Sdcard of tablet that I need to read by my application. When I tried testing it on Marshmallow devices It is throwing error that Directory is not found while It's there.

Can anybody help me what could be a probable cause of it and what is the prompt solution.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html (required from Android 6.0 on)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a device with Android 6.0(API 23) or higher, you **must request permission at runtime**.

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is classified as a **dangerous** permission.

So, before implement reading external storage logic, you must ask user permissions

To do that, first need to add this in your activity

```
// Request permissions
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
```

Then you will check if the user has granted permissions adding this override method.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d("PERMISSION", "SUCCESS");
            }else{
               Log.d("PERMISSION", "FAIL");
            }
            return;
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Log.d("PERMISSION", "SUCCESS");
            }else{
                Log.d("PERMISSION", "FAIL");
            }
            return;
    }
}
```